# No buffer space available

Tags: postgresql, yii, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

[image]

I am using an application in Yii and postgres database. When i run the application on live server(not local system) i am getting this error

"CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: No buffer space available (0x00002747/10055)
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

I have 5 active client database. The error not showing every time. How to solve this problem..?

Comment: be sure you have properly configured the proceted/config/main.php  db component for the live server database .. and be sure the database is on ..

Answer (score 4):

This error message is thrown by PostgreSQL when a Winsock operation returns the error `WSAENOBUFS`.

Microsoft [describes the error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAENOBUFS) as:

> No buffer space available.
>
> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

It is a problem of the Windows operating system. I don't know a lot about Windows, but it sounds like a resource shortage.

Maybe there are too many open TCP connections?